# Probability $P(A|X)$

Tags: probability

$A$ and $B$ are two dices.

$A$ has six faces numbered $1,2,3,3,4,5$ .

$B$ has six faces numbered $2,2,3,4,4,5$

$1)$ $A$ is thrown twice . Find the probability of sum of two numbers are $6$

$2)$ $B$ is thrown twice . Find the probability of sum of two numbers are $6$

$3)$ $A$ and $B $ are put in a box. And we take one from the box and throw it twice . If it is given that the sum of to numbers is $6$ , then find the probability of "taken dice is $A$"

For $1)$ I got $$\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{2}{9}$$

For $2)$ I got $$\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{4}$$

For $3)$ I used the formula $$P(A|X)=\frac{P(A\cap X)}{P(X)}$$
where $P(X)=$ Prob of sum is $6$  and $P(A)=$ Prob of $A$ dice is taken

Are my answers correct ?

Can anyone explain how to do the last part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers are a-okay.

(1) $\mathsf P(X\mid A)=\tfrac 8{36}=\tfrac 29\quad\color{green}\checkmark$

(2) $\mathsf P(X\mid B)=\tfrac 9{36}=\tfrac 14\quad\color{green}\checkmark$

For (3), use: $~\mathsf P(A\cap X)=\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(X\mid A)~$ and $~\mathsf P(X)=\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(X\mid A)+ \mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(X\mid B)~$.

PS: as noted Doug M, keeping note of when the denominators are $36$ means a lot of easy cancelations.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid X)~=~&\dfrac{\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(X\mid A)}{\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(X\mid A)+\mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(X\mid B)}\\[1ex]~=~&\dfrac{\color{gray}{\dfrac 12\dfrac{\color{black}8}{36}}}{\color{gray}{\dfrac 12\dfrac{\color{black}8}{36}+\dfrac 12\dfrac{\color{black}9}{36}}}\\[1ex] ~=~& \dfrac{8}{17}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you keep everything in $\frac 1{36}$

The direct way to do is to say that there are $17$ ways to roll a $6.$ And $8$ of them happen if $A$ is chosen.

More formally:

$P(X|A) = \frac 8{36}\\
P(X|B) = \frac 9{36}$

$P(A|X) = \frac {\frac 8{36}}{\frac 8{36} + \frac {9}{36}}$